# My approach for JWT - REST API

Tags: web-services, rest, security, jwt

My question is specifically regarding my approach of JWT with REST implementation.

I am using AngularJS on the client side and PHP on server side.

As soon as page loads for the first time, I fire one GET request to server and get signature from web service (encoded signature).

When someone opens the web page, we present login form and when user fills it correctly, we send login information to server in JWT encrypted format:

```
Header(ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE).Payload(Login form data).Signature(Received from the first GET web service call)
```

Now, after login, we got the `exp` i.e. token expire time out data from server. Now we show one more form to the logged in user. It is used to create employees. So, my implementation is:

- We present the form (using angularjs)
- User inputs the data
- System validates the form
- If the form entries are correct then system triggers `addEmployee` webservice. BUT the data we pass in `header authorization bearer` only. For example:

`Host: mysite.com
POST: /services/addEmployee
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer Header(ALGORITHM & TOKEN TYPE).PAYLOAD(Employee form data + EXP token expire time received in the response of login web service).Signature`

So, here we don't pass anything on the request body. Even though this is being POST request. And on the server side, we just decode the Bearer and get the payload.

I really don't want to send any data in plain text format. For example, if we send POST data in body then anyone can see what's being passed. I want to encrypt my web services up to some level. Is this approach correct or harmful in anyway?

Comment: Why not use https?

Comment: JWT only works over HTTPS.  Well, any static cookie-based session scheme only works over HTTPS.

Comment: @MK. JWT works with both HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: @RobertMoskal Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976728/how-to-configure-ssl-certificates-with-charles-web-proxy-and-the-latest-android) - using Charles anyone can debug HTTPS request very easily.

Comment: My question is related specifically to headers. Is it really fine to send all the payload and signature data into `Header Authorization: Bearer <token>` format, and leave the request body totally blank?

Comment: @RaviManiyar depends on your definition of working.  not secure.

Comment: @MK. Thanks for getting back to me. Can please you let me know even if its encoded, why its not secure?

Comment: because if it is not encrypted attacker can intercept it and send his request with the same JWT.

Comment: @MK., no its encrypted, see my above comments. The header authorization goes like this:
`Header Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWV9.TJVA95OrM7E2cBab30RMHrHDcEfxjoYZgeFONFh7HgQ`

Comment: it is not encrypted, it is signed and encoded.  I can't create my own JWTs because I don't have the key you signed it with, but I can send requests with your JWTs if I can intercept them.

Comment: @MK. That makes sense. Thanks. Can you please let me know how to ENCRYPT the JWT? I can't seem to find that in the official documentation.

Comment: You don't encrypt the JWT.   That's not the point of it.  JWT proves your identity (and perhaps your rights) using a signature.  Encryption is done by https.

Comment: @MK. Got it. Thanks man. Please post this as the answer and I will accept it and then we can close this thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think your approach is wrong.
The JWT payload is not intented to hold sensitive information. Anyone can read it.
You could encript the payload, however it's not the way JWT are usually used for.

Usually a JWT payload should contain claims that are not sensitive or request-specific (such your employees form data). Keep that data in the request body, so you can reuse the JWT for different API calls no matter what HTTP verb and params you use for your different needs.

The entire request will be encripted with SSL so you're not sending any plain text data. Never use this without HTTPS, as anybody could get your token and impersonate the user.

Hope it helps, regards.