# Charles Web Debugging Proxy does not identify Android character encoding

Tags: android, windows, proxy, charles-proxy

I'm trying to use Charles to monitor activity on my Android phone, and when I look at the response, the request and response tabs display the data improperly.

In the command prompt on windows, I got my `IPv4 using ipconfig` and modified the wifi on the phone to set up a manual proxy with the address retrieved as the hostname and the port as `8888`.

The application appeared to be responding to the phone and logging information. When I check the request and response section however, the messages are improperly decoded. In the notes I get a `SSL Proxying not enabled for this host: enable in Proxy Settings, SSL locations` message.

When installing the Charles Certificate, I'm asked if it's for vpns and apps, or wifi, and I've tried both.

---

Update:

I switched to [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) and found that fiddler has a "decode" button that properly decodes.

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered check - [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976728/how-to-configure-ssl-certificates-with-charles-web-proxy-and-the-latest-android)

[image]